# Firebase database REST API, get throws 401 error

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've spent all the afternoon researching and then checked the related answers and none of them solved my problem, Excuse me if it's duplicated as I didn't find it.

I have a realtime database for my **android** app. However, I would like to get the formatted json in a REST client (postman), just for comfort (so I can save the json locally for mock purposes).

Here are the rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "contents": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

In theory (if I'm not mistaken), I should be able to retrieve the data with:

```
https://project-f7de2.firebaseio.com/contents.json
```

But I get this error:

```
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 12 Nov 2017 18:03:00 GMT
Server: nginx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
```

I also followed this links explaining authentication in requests:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

So I tried debugging my app, getting the tokenID for the logged user and immediately sending the request in my REST client:

```
 mUser.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                String token_id = task.getResult().getToken();
                Log.d("I'm using this", token_id);
            }
        });
```

And then:

```
https://project-f7de2.firebaseio.com/contents.json?auth=<token_id>
```

But still, 401 error, permission denied.

I'm fairly new to firebase and REST clients.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the URL you are using, is `<database_name>` the Project ID shown in the Firebase console project settings tab?  Something like `myproject-c4adb` or `project-1234567`?

Comment: It's: project-f7de2
I think that part is correct as otherwise the error wouldn't be "Unauthorized". Also, I tried changing the path /contents for another that doesn't exist and the feedback is correct. I'm updating the question to clarify the project name.

Comment: You security rules allow unauthorized read of `contents`.  Try a simple GET of `https://project-f7de2.firebaseio.com/contents.json` without any auth param.  That should be accepted.

Comment: I did that, I wrote "In theory (if I'm not mistaken), I should be able to retrieve the data with: https://project-f7de2.firebaseio.com/contents.json". I agree with you, this should work, but it isn't, so I posted the issue here in case my mistake is elsewhere and I have tunnel vision :(

Comment: To eliminate the possibility of a typo somewhere, temporarily change your [rules to make your DB totally public](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules),  and then try the GET again.

Comment: That worked indeed! Thanks a lot mate. I still would like a proper explanation about authentication but you saved me for today.

Answer (score 8):

You are denying any access to the DB, if you want anyone to write in the "contents" child, you must change the `".write"` parameter to `true` or some other rule. `false` only gives access to the admin.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "contents": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So, can you suggest other rules except "true"?

Comment: This is insecure. Don't use it when dealing with sensitive data

Answer (score -1):

You can provide the time in milliseconds till it can be accessed, something like this -

```
`{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "now < 1648146600000",
        ".write": "now < 1648146600000"
    }
}`
```